# Trying to make values of two dataframes corresponding to pairs R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes in which I would like to merge based on country code.

For example my data looks as follows:

```
x = data.frame("countryCode" = c("AD", "AE", "AF", "AT", "BA"), "lang" = c("Catalan", "Arabic", "Dari", "German", "Romani"), "langCountryPop" = c(31000, 744000, 5600000, 7500000, 400000), "lat" = c(41.75,26,35,52, 45), "lon" = c(2,49,66,10,21))

y = data.frame("iso2_x" = c("AE", "AT", "BA"), "iso2_y" = c("AD", "AF", "AE"), "distance" = c(1243213, 1234123, 45423535))
```

I would like to merge X with Y so that Y now looks like:

```
y = data.frame("iso2_x" = c("AE", "AT", "BA"), "lang" = c("Arabic", "German", "Romani"), "lat" = c(26,52,45), "lon" = c(49,10,21), "iso2_y" = c("AD", "AF", "AE"), "lang" = c("Catalan", "Dari", "Arabic"), "lat" = c(41.75,35,26), "lon" = c(2,66,49), "distance" = c(1243213, 1234123, 45423535))
```

How can I match the "countryCode" column from X to the "iso2_x" and "iso2_y" columns in Y and add the respective columns from X to Y as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way

```
   library(tidyverse)
    y %>% 
      pivot_longer(-distance, names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "set")) %>% 
      left_join(x, by = c("iso2" = "countryCode")) %>% 
      pivot_wider(distance, 
                  names_from = set,
                  values_from = c(iso2, lang, lat, lon)) %>% 
      select(ends_with("_x"), ends_with("_y"), distance)

# A tibble: 3 x 9
  iso2_x lang_x lat_x lon_x iso2_y lang_y  lat_y lon_y distance
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 AE     Arabic    26    49 AD     Catalan  41.8     2  1243213
2 AT     German    52    10 AF     Dari     35      66  1234123
3 BA     Romani    45    21 AE     Arabic   26      49 45423535
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use just two joins...

```r
x <- data.frame("countryCode" = c("AD", "AE", "AF", "AT", "BA"), "lang" = c("Catalan", "Arabic", "Dari", "German", "Romani"), "langCountryPop" = c(31000, 744000, 5600000, 7500000, 400000), "lat" = c(41.75,26,35,52, 45), "lon" = c(2,49,66,10,21))
y <- data.frame("iso2_x" = c("AE", "AT", "BA"), "iso2_y" = c("AD", "AF", "AE"), "distance" = c(1243213, 1234123, 45423535))


library(dplyr)

y %>% 
  left_join(x, by = c('iso2_x' = 'countryCode')) %>% 
  left_join(x, by = c('iso2_y' = 'countryCode'), suffix = c('', '_y'))
#>   iso2_x iso2_y distance   lang langCountryPop lat lon  lang_y langCountryPop_y
#> 1     AE     AD  1243213 Arabic         744000  26  49 Catalan            31000
#> 2     AT     AF  1234123 German        7500000  52  10    Dari          5600000
#> 3     BA     AE 45423535 Romani         400000  45  21  Arabic           744000
#>   lat_y lon_y
#> 1 41.75     2
#> 2 35.00    66
#> 3 26.00    49
```